# Multi page figures side by side containing own subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

For my thesis I want to have two figures placed beside each other, where each figure consists of five subfigures that need to be displayed beneath each other. I managed to do this using a combination of the packages `subfig`, `caption` and `float`. However, now the two figures fill an entire page, and therefore the placement of the figures makes no sense. Also, I don't need all the sufigures to be on one page, however I do want to keep the two different figures, with each its own subfigures.

When using different figure environments with `\ContinuedFloat` the naming of the subfigures of the different figures is messed up.

Part of my code now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \noindent\subfloat[1a]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{image1}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1b]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this008}}    
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1c]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this009}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1d]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this010}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1d]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this011}}
        \caption{Caption figure 1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \noindent\subfloat[2a]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot001}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2b]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot003}}  
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2c]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot004}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2d]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot005}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2e]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot006}}  
        \caption{Caption figure 2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces what I want but it cannot span over multiple pages. I want to have:

```
 1a          2a
 1b          2b
-pagebreak-
 1c          2c
 1d          2d
 1e          2e
 caption 1   caption 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a `longtable` to create a multipage figure.  The entry to the list of figures is written separately at the start.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\listcaption}[1]{\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces#1}}}%

\newsavebox{\boxA}
\newsavebox{\boxB}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\savebox{\boxA}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \captionof{figure}[]{Caption figure 1}
\end{minipage}}% increments figure counter on creation only
\listcaption{Caption figure 1}% write to listoffigures
%
\savebox{\boxB}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \captionof{figure}[]{Caption figure 2}
\end{minipage}}%
\listcaption{Caption figure 2}% write to listoffigures
%
\begin{longtable}{cc}
  \endhead
  \usebox{\boxA} & \usebox{\boxB} \\
  \endfoot
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{image1} & \includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot001} \\
  \nopagebreak 1a & 2a \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{this008} & \includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot003} \\
  \nopagebreak 1b & 2b \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{this009} & \includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot004} \\
  \nopagebreak 1c & 2c \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{this010} & \includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot005} \\
  \nopagebreak 1d & 2d \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{this011} & \includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot006} \\
  \nopagebreak 1e & 2e \\[\abovecaptionskip]
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a neat way to solve my problem. However, it is indeed undesirable to have the entries in the list of figures, but I am guessing you don't know any way around this?

Comment: Actually, I know several.  I assume you would like to use the first page instead of the last page.

Comment: Yes I think that would be the best way to go

Answer (score 1):

Not nice, but with some manipulation of the `figure` and the `subfigure` counter it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \noindent\subfloat[1a]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{image1}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1b]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this008}}    
        \caption{Caption figure 1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \noindent\subfloat[2a]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot001}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2b]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot003}}  
        \caption{Caption figure 2}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \ContinuedFloat
        \noindent
        \subfloat[1c]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this009}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1d]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this010}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[1e]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{this011}}
        \caption{Caption figure 1}
        \addtocounter{subfigure}{-3}%
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \noindent
        \subfloat[2c]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot004}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2d]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot005}}
        \hfill
        \subfloat[2e]{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{d3plot006}}  
        \caption{Caption figure 2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]