# List of Figures with Many 'Repetitious Plots'

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a document which has many similar plots, that typically have the same caption except for a minor difference such as temperature.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\foreach \x in {100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000}{
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{MyPicture}
        \caption[Figure for Plot at Temperature of \x{}K]{Figure Caption for Plot at Temperature of \x{}K}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Example]

Now what I would like to do, is one of two things:

Either to condense all of the listings into a single line item in the list of figures -- ideally with the page range instead of a single page:

```
0.1 - 0.10 Figures for plots at Temperatures of 100 to 1000K          1-10
```

Or to secondly have the full listing for the first record, and a modified record for the subsequent to reflect only the minor change, ensuring the critical 100,200,300K etc... all line up vertically.

```
0.1 Figures for plots at Temperatures of 100K          1
0.2 .....................................200K          2
0.3 .....................................300K          3
```

Has anyone had to deal with this type of thing before? I have pages and pages of items in my list of figures, and just want to condense it a bit or make it a little easier to read.

Comment: Normally one would use a bunch of subfigures for something like this, but since this takes 3 pages that isn't an option.  One could use a longtable instead.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357102/multi-page-figures-side-by-side-containing-own-subfigures/357173?s=11|0.0545#357173

Comment: @JohnKormylo yeah, my actual document has for example 12 related images spread out over 6 pages, so subcaptions / subfigures aren't an option.

Answer (score 1):

The second  alternative is easier and nicer,  but I changed the dots with  `''` in order to left the dots at the right of the captions:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\scap{\makebox[\widthof{Figures for plots at Temperatures of }]%
{\xleaders\hbox to 4em{ '' }\hfill}}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{figure}\caption{Figures for plots at Temperatures of 100K}
\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}\caption[\scap 200K]{Figures for plots at Temperatures of 200K}
\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}\caption[\scap 300K]{Figures for plots at Temperatures of 300K}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Anyway, if you want remove the dots, just insert in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1000} 
\makeatother
```

And change the quotation mark by `\dotfill` in the macro definition:

> [image: wme]