# Link from Label in \addtocontents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I need to create a manual entry in the list of figures using `\addtocontents` (yes I need `\addtocontents` rather than `\addcontentsline`).

When using the `hyperref` package, an extra argument is added to the standard command, for the link. I am trying to base the 'link' off a label, but the following is throwing an error:

**Undefined control sequence. ... {0.1}{\ignorespaces Short}}{2}{figure.0.1}**

I am sure this is a simple problem to solve, but I have had no luck. Can one of the LaTeX experts help me out?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption[Short]{My Caption}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\addtocontents{lof}{
    \protect\contentsline
    {figure}
    {\numberline{1}A Manual Entry}
    {\pageref{fig:myfigure}}
    {figure.\ref{fig:myfigure}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HOW???
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a trailing white space after the `\ref{fig:myfigure}` -- this confuses the anchor generation in addition. It's not the cause of your problem, however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ref` isn't expandable, so this is nothing that can be written this way to the `.aux` file (and then to the `.lof`)

I suggest to use `\getrefpagenumber` and `\getrefbykeydefault{labelname}{anchor}{}`, both are expandable commands, the second one extracts the correct `hyper` anchor -- there is no guarantee that the anchor to a `figure` labeled entity is really starting with `figure` nor is the rest of the anchor made of the output of `\ref`.

Consider the example that `\thefigure` is defined as `\thechapter.\alph{figure}`.

The usual anchor still use the integer expression of the counter:
It is most likely `figure.0.1` and not `figure.0.a`.

Since this is hidden from the user, `\getrefbykeydefault` is the better variant here.

Usually, this requires `refcount` to be loaded, but `hyperref` does this already (both packages are written by the same author)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption[Short]{My Caption}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\addtocontents{lof}{
    \protect\contentsline
    {figure}
    {\numberline{1}A Manual Entry}
    {\getpagerefnumber{fig:myfigure}}
    {\getrefbykeydefault{fig:myfigure}{anchor}{}} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HOW???
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Personally I would not use such `\addtocontents` in this way directly, but there's is no real use - case and I don't understand why this seems to be necessary

Comment: Thanks. I am extending this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362004/list-of-figures-with-many-repetitious-plots, and condensing multiple lines into a single line (my list of figures in my thesis is 10 pages long or something), where the figure number becomes a range, and the page number also becomes a range of numbers, like: [1-4 Figures One, Two, Three and Four................ 11-14]

Comment: if you know how to add a line to the toc or list of figures, where the figure number is actually a range of figures, and the page numbers are a range of numbers (ie a single line that represents X number of figures with extremely similar captions) then I am all ears.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: That's another question indeed. I can think of a solution where the `\caption` command is changed and 'collects' the information from some figure environments and writes this to the `.aux` file then, but what is the criterion for this collection? Why figures 1 - 4 and not 1 -6, for example? That's something not really to be detected automatically.

Comment: I have asked another question, which also demonstrates what I am trying to achieve. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385556/condense-figures-into-single-line-in-lof